# Code for creating three vertical columns in Wordpress Bootstrap theme

Tags: theme-development, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make Wordpress theme with bootstrap 3.x. This is my first theme and I am experimenting with Wordpress and bootstrap various features. I would like to use Wordpress sticky post feature to create three side by side columns, but I do not know how to do that.
If I use

```
?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$mythemename_post_format = get_post_format();
get_template_part('templates/post', $mythemename_post_format);
<?php endif; ?>
```

all the posts including those which are checked as sticky posts will appear under the three columns I am taking about.

My plan is to add the codes in the following way:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <!—code for the first column—>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <!—code for the second column—>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <!—code for the third column—>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (have_posts()){ ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()){ 
        the_post();
        if(is_sticky()){ ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <?php //put what you want, Hey you inside the loop now ?>
            </div>
        <?php }else{
                  $mythemename_post_format = get_post_format();
                  get_template_part('templates/post', $mythemename_post_format);
              }
    } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Maybe I was not clear above, but I just need to know how I can call the first three sticky posts for the three respective divs with col-sm-4 classes.

Comment: OK, I edit My code to check if the post sticky or not, You can just use `is_sticky()` inside the loop